# XQuery A constructor function must have exactly one argument (subtract-dates())

Tags: xml, xquery

I am current using the subtract-dates(arg1, arg2) function in the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace, however when I give it two date parameters the compiler gives this warning: "A constructor function must have exactly one argument"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no subtract-dates() function in the XSD namespace. The processor you are using seems to be thinking "if it's in the XSD namespace it must be a constructor function, and if it's a constructor function it must have a single argument".

You're probably looking at op:subtract-dates(), which is not a user-visible function, but an internal function that appears in the specification for the purpose of explaining the semantics of the "-" operator when applied to dates and durations.

Comment: Thanks Michael, so how would I subtract two xs:date values? Would I have to make some sort of conversion?

Comment: Use the subtraction operator (-).